# MobX Store Responsibilities

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx

I recently started working on a project with MobX. I never used MobX before so I am quite confused about one thing.

What are MobX store responsibilities?

1) Should MobX `@action`, `@computed` return `html/jsx`? In official 10 minutes MobX tutorial https://mobx.js.org/getting-started.html there is a `@computed get report`. That is just an example right?

```
@computed get report() {
    if (this.todos.length === 0)
        return "<none>";
    return `Next todo: "${this.todos[0].task}". ` +
        `Progress: ${this.completedTodosCount}/${this.todos.length}`;
}
```

2) Is it a good idea to call API in `@action`? Like this?

```
@action
submitProfileInformation = params => {
  return post("apiendpoint", {
    body: params
  }).then(resp => {
    this.firstName = resp.first_name;
    return "ok";
  });
};
```

**I come from the redux world and the way I see it `store` should only store and mutate values. Actions would react component let know that something has changed so that they would rerender. Is that correct?**

Comment: MobX has nothing to do with html/jsx. It's a plain javascript store. And yes it's fine to call an API in an `@action` :) just remember you need to bind the responses to a `@observable` in the store scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It doesn't return any html or jsx. It's just a sample and it returns only string.
2. Only the `then` section should be marked as action.

Concepts are the same. It's up to you to follow the best practices or abusing flexiblity of mobx and doing bad things.
I recommand you to read this article:
https://mobx.js.org/best/store.html

Answer (score 0):

MobX store is for storing application states, including observable and non-observable data. (similar to Redux Stores, although Redux doesn't have observable)

MobX actions are any functions that modify the observable data. There's no rule saying that you must put actions in store, but it's good practice to do so.

For you question: `Actions would react component let know that something has changed so that they would rerender.` Answer is yes and no. Actions are functions that modify observable data. Your observer components react to changes of observable data, not action functions. But since actions always modify observable data, so calling an action function should trigger observer components to react.

@computed decorator simply creates observable data that is computed from other observable data (similar to getter functions)